# Why do images disappear when emailing Google Sheet as PDF and saving it in drive, using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, pdf-generation

I found this script converting Google Sheet into PDF, emailing the PDF and saving it in a folder. It worked capturing all data including images.
However, when I added more information (rows) and images, the images disappeared. Below is the formula for the cell image.

[image]

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("xxxx");

  const value = ss.getSheetByName("xxx").getRange("K2").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  const subject = 'Audit Report';

  const body = "Here's a copy of the Audit Report";

  const url = 'xxxx';

  const exportOptions =
     'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
     '&size=letter' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
     '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
     '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
     '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
     '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
     '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
     '&gid=1275739079'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.

     var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ 
     
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

    // Generate the PDF file
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();


    // Send the PDF file as an attachement
    const docName = ss.getSheetByName("PDF").getRange("D6").getValue().toString()
    const docID = ss.getSheetByName("PDF").getRange("D11").getValue().toString() +".pdf"

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
        fileName: docName + "_" + docID,
        content: response.getBytes(),
        mimeType: "application/pdf"
    }]
});

   const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("PDF").getRange("D6").getValue().toString() + "_" + 
   ss.getSheetByName("PDF").getRange("D11").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
   DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx').createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
```

}

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `However, when I added more information (rows) and images, the images disappeared.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, here's the sheet link for more information. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-JppLZ-GvVVQq7hNgEhxmzE-D0CucBoCbP9pQJjRsOA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand about `However, when I added more information (rows) and images, the images disappeared.`.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, basically all data apart from images are appearing in the PDF attachment.